# WHY my Datepicker looks so weired?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, google-app-engine

I'm trying to use jquery UI. I download everything and follow the instruction, I add such  code in my html:

```
<link type="text/css" href="/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(function() {
         $( "#id_myDate" ).datepicker({
             inline: true
         });
     });
</script>
.....
<div>Date: <input type="text" id="id_myDate" name="deadLine"></div>
```

When I load this page, the Datepicker looks so weired.

[image]

What's wrong? When I download jquery UI, I open the index.html and everything works fine(including datepicker), but when I put it into my app, it looks bad.

BTW. My browser is Chrome(I test this in firefox too, same problem), and I'm working on a google appengine app in python.

Thank you.

------------------------**EDIT**---------------------------

I'm sorry. Because this is a google appengine, so I should configure my static files, such as js and css. I forget to configure my css files in app.yaml. Now, I add this in yaml file:

```
- url: /js
static_dir: js

- url: /css
static_dir: css
```

js and css are the name of dir where these files located.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Is your browser loading the css file correctly?  Press F12 in Chrome, click the network tab then reload the page to see if there were any errors loading files.

Comment: have you tried checking the error on chrome, using the console. just press **F12**, likely you are missing something

Comment: @KyleTrauberman You are right. The css isn't loaded, because in google appengine, I need to configure my css dir in a index file. I miss this step. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
```

add this code to the head of your html

Comment: This fixed it for me. Thank you, sir.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the css file isn't loading correctly. Check to make sure its loaded properly.

In chrome, you can press <kbd>F12</kbd> to open the developer tools. Click the network tab, then refresh your page.  You will see a list of every request sent to the webserver, including any errors.  Make sure your css file is loaded correctly.

Comment: F12 is really handy. Problem is already solved. I edited this question with the solution.Thank you:)