# DatePicker has no formatting

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui-datepicker

Please see the code below, which I took from here: https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#min-max

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Restrict date range</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: -20, maxDate: "+1M +10D", dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" });
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" readonly="true"></p>


</body>
</html>
```

The DatePicker looks like this in all my browsers (Chrome; Firefox; IE and Edge):

[image]

I want it to look smoother; maybe like this (as in the link):

[image]

I have spent two hours Googling this and have found nothing except this: [WHY my Datepicker looks so weired?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10561137/why-my-datepicker-looks-so-weired).  However, the solution did not work for me.

Comment: To me it appears as in the link. Have you turned off JS or something?

Comment: @SuperDJ, it happens in all browsers.

Comment: @SuperDJ, could it be something to do with the fact that I am just copying and pasting the code into a file and then double clicking on the file (.html) to run it.  Do I have to run it from a web server e.g. IIS?

Comment: I doubt that is the reason. Atleast I'm still able to load files from the web that way.

Comment: Are you trying to open the html as a file in your browser? Then `//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css` won't work as a URL probably. Have you checked the network tab in your dev tools, if the CSS is actually loaded?

Comment: try to use this cdn url for css "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"

Comment: @SuperDJ, it works as expected when I load the webpage from IIS.  Any ideas why it does not work when I load it by double clicking on the file?

Comment: @Gaurav Moolani, see my comment above.

Comment: The only reason I can think of is that `//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css` is seen as a local path. Try: `https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css`

Comment: @SuperDJ, thanks.  That was it (I have marked another answer below).  Could you have a look at my follow on question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52914225/using-datepicker-with-net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
```

by

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
```

You are missing the protocol `https:` at the start of the `href` value. I assume resolving a protocol-less URL isn't supported if you're not serving the page from a webserver.

if you want to check the page using the `file://`protocol.

Comment: Could you have a look at my follow on question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52914225/using-datepicker-with-net ? Thanks.