# Make @Html.TextBox("datepicker") readonly (so user cannot type)

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core

Please see the View code below:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="MemberView">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="DOB" class="control-label"></label>
                @Html.TextBox("datepicker")                   
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

How do I make @Html.TextBox("datepicker") readonly (so only the datepicker can populate it) i.e. a user cannot type in it.  I have spent one hour Googling this and have already looked here: [Using DatePicker with .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52914225/using-datepicker-with-net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `readonly` property by passing an anonymous object as the third argument.

The `null` (second argument) is there to keep the input value empty. Of course you could fill it if necessary.

```
@Html.TextBox("datepicker", null, new { @readonly = "readonly" })
```

*Note: The `@` symbol is required, because 'readonly' is a reserved keyword.*

Please keep in mind that the user *is* able to manipulate the HTML by removing the `readonly` attribute. Proper value checking in the back-end is required to handle the value safely.

Comment: Thanks.  However, this just does not work.  It simply writes new { @readonly = "readonly" } in the textbox (and the textbox is still editable).  Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: You could try the `disabled` property.

Comment: @Html.TextBox("datepicker", "",new { @readonly = "readonly" }) does seem to work (note there are three arguments).  However, I do not know why.

Comment: Well, that was my bad. Sorry about that. The *second* argument is the current value for the input. The **third** parameter is for attributes. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks.  What is the second parameter for (the default value I guess)? +1.

Comment: The value for the input. Mostly used for edit pages.

Comment: I have asked a follow on question here if you are interested: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52949847/using-the-html-5-datepicker-with-the-date-input-field